# Runtime Error on server while activating site collection feature

Tags: sharepoint-server, error, feature-activation

I have creating content type using visual studio.
while activating site collection feature i'm facing this error 
[image]

Comment: Can you please try turning on customErrors and check in ULS and Event Viewer for any hint?

Comment: Can you share the ULS log ?

Comment: I had look in ULS and found that its because of Content type and Site Columns that I have created.. Now my issues resolve. Thanks